# Trying to make different hover animations for multiple images in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

So i have a few images in HTML like this

```
<div class="thumb"> 
    <a href="website1"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="name1"></a>
    <a href="website2"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="name2"></a>
    <a href="website3"><img src="image3.jpg" alt="name3"></a>                      
</div>
```

I'm trying to make them have a specific hover effect - when you hover on image1, image1 gets bigger and image2 and image3 get smaller and with reduced opacity. This is an example with only three images but in reality i have varying number of images on different pages.

I tried this in CSS but it doesn't seem to work properly. The problem is the first effect is triggered whenever the mouse is above .thumb and not above an image, but i haven't found a way to adress all images other than the one which is being hovered.

```
.thumb:hover img {
    opacity: .25;
    transform: scale(.8);
}

.thumb img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

I prefer to have it in CSS but if it requires javascript it's ok. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: give each element a distinct ID, or use classes like effect1, effect2, effect3 to have multiples that behave the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are after sibling selector:

```css
.thumb{
  display: inline-block;
}
.thumb:hover img{
  opacity: .25;
  transform: scale(.8);
  transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
}

.thumb a:hover img{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb"> 
    <a href="website1"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/6666ff" alt="name1"></a>
    <a href="website2"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ff6666" alt="name2"></a>
    <a href="website3"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/66ff66" alt="name3"></a>                      
</div>
```

## UPDATE

If you are after a JS solution it would be something like this:

```js
$('.thumb a').hover(function(){
  $(this).siblings().addClass('shrink').removeClass('grow');
  $(this).addClass('grow').removeClass('shrink');
}, function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('shrink');
  $(this).removeClass('grow');
});
```

```css
.thumb a{
  margin: 20px;
}
.thumb a.shrink img{
  opacity: .25;
  transform: scale(.8);
  transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
}

.thumb a.grow img{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb"> 
    <a href="website1"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/6666ff" alt="name1"></a>
    <a href="website2"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ff6666" alt="name2"></a>
    <a href="website3"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/66ff66" alt="name3"></a>                      
</div>
```

Comment: Ok this is the one I'm looking for. But look at the example when you hover on the right of the images or inbetween images it triggers the effect. And it's not supposed to be like that.

Comment: This one is pretty good. The only problem left is inbetween the images. I have alot of space in my layolt because the images are not square but circlular.

Comment: There is no CSS solution to this, if you are not OK with the spaces. So if you are after such a solution, you need to use JS. Please let me know if there is need for that so I can edit my answer and add the JS solution

Comment: If there is some way to do it whitout using .thumb it would be best.
is it possible when hovering on one image to generate one effect for the same image and another effect for the rest of the images,

Comment: Yes please. I would like to see it done with javascript.

Comment: @MarkShark OK, please check UPDATE in a minute

Answer (score 1):

This can now be done directly with css using ::has pseudo class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

(Currently only available in safari, with other browsers' support rolling out)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add particular classes for different type of hover that you want and add them in the img tags that you like?

```
.thumb img.opacity-1:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.thumb img.opacity-05:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
.thumb img {
 opacity: 0.25;
 transform: scale(0.8);
}

.thumb img:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(1.2);
}
```